# Apple devices - "Vibrating feel" when charging

Tags: electricity, conductivity, apple

I am absolutely not experienced when it comes to electrical stuff at all which is why I hope you can help me out on this one because I am a bit worried right now.

I own a bunch of Apple devices and after making the switch to a new 2017 MacBook Pro I noticed a weird, vibrating feel when striking over the aluminum. I instantly thought that it has to be related to the device being charged right now and indeed: Depending on whether it's charging or not and depending on the shoes I am wearing I can feel this weird, vibrating, tingly feeling.

So, to underline the fact that I have absolutely no clue about any of that I hope that anyone in here feels like giving me a hand and explain to me what I am experiencing here. I am indeed worried because apparently that applies to all of my current Apple devices - The same happens when I use my non original charger (with 24W) on my iPad.

Comment: This is a common problem with cheapo chargers that aren't earthed.

Comment: Also https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/331868/how-to-check-if-there-is-electric-current-on-material-surface

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies, I'll get my Mac charger changed then :)

Comment: I can't see that this is a duplicate. I haven't seen the VIBRATION aspect mentioned before, nor an explanation of it.  (though the electrical source of the current is a common topic)

Comment: I think the "sensation" is not vibration, but the 120 volts (or lower voltages, depending on your body resistance) forcing a small current thru your fingers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This effect has a name. [Electrovibration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrovibration).
And it's due to the charger not being grounded. Leaking a tiny amount of AC current trough [capacitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor) effects in the transformer and Y-class capacitors.
As by design.

This is a recurring question here, see the topics in the question comments.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Considering that it happens with my official Mac charger as well as my cheap iPhone charger, I am gonna let Apple exchange it.

Comment: Since it's a recurring question, you should have closed it, not added yet another answer.

Comment: @pipe there are many answers, but none of them are very clear and simple to understand.

Comment: @bqcqON replacing the charger will not remove this effect.

Comment: So you add your answer to the already present questions.

Comment: @Jeroen3  Cool. Never heard of it, but the effect is incredibly strong on my laptop, and I have always assumed it was an "electricity through the nerves" effect and not a true mechanical one

Comment: @VladimirCravero Yes. Until someone writes an in-depth full answer to this we can all link to.

Comment: You can solve this by grounding the computer using [Apple's extension cable](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MK122LL/A/power-adapter-extension-cable) or a [third party grounded duckhead](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0B452LS67/).